# writing a function that splits an interval in c

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that's supposed to increase or decrease an interval between 1 and 100, depending on which parameter it takes.

It starts from `(0,100)`, then, if `parameter=-1` it becomes `(0,50)`, if `parameter=1` afterwards, it becomes `(25, 50)`. It stores the last "guess" and gives the next one based on that.

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong when `parameter=-1` (the part where it's supposed to decrease the interval). Other parts work fine, you don't have to look at them, they give the expected output BUT this (-1) one gives `25 12 6 3 2` instead of `25 12 6 3 1`.

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int NextGuess(int  param) {

    int num;
    static int a=1, b=99;

    //this part is where it goes wrong (the output doesn't match with the expected one)//
    if (param==-1) //less
    {
        b-=(a+b)/2 - a+1;
        num=(a+b)/2;
    }
    //these below are doing fine//

    if (param==1) //greater
    {
        a+=(a+b)/2 - a+1;
        num=(a+b)/2;
    }

    if (param==0) //equal
    num=(a+b)/2;

    return num;
}
//main isn't important, it's just for testing the output//
int main() {
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
//output should be: 25 12 6 3 1  but this gives: 25 12 6 3 2    
    return 0;
}
```

If someone could just point to what I'm doing wrong in that part, I've been thinking about this simple thing for far too long now...

other examples of what the function is supposed to output when called:

```
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(-1));
printf ("%d ", NextGuess(1));
//output: 75 62 56 59
```

Comment: Aside: why do you even use pointers for this?

Comment: Why are you using those pointers? They're completely unnecessary, and only serve to make the code more difficult to read

Comment: Since you're using pointers here in an unnecessarily complicated way, you may need a better C programming reference to learn from. This is not how you'd normally tackle a problem like this in C. These pointers point at a `static` variable, and that's also a messy solution. You might want to have some kind of state `struct` you pass in.

Comment: @PhilM well.. there's no particular reason actually.. I did it for learning purpose only, sorry if it hurts your eyes! :-(

Comment: @tadman okayyy, i'm sorry, I'll remove the pointers, no big deal :-( they're not part of the question tho! It's about the output...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with learning, but this is like using a hammer to drive in a screw, it's not the correct tool for the job. If you want to learn more about pointers, write a linked list implementation or dive into C strings in more detail, both of which require a solid understanding of how pointers work and what they can do.

Comment: @tadman will do! i should've posted the readable code in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some math. You can break out the math into separate lines and step through with a debugger to confirm.

For the call that returns a guess of 2, your statics are `a == 1` and `b == 6`.

So for the (cleaned up) code

```
b-=(a+b)/2 - a + 1;
num=(a+b)/2;
```

we get:

```
`a` + `b` == 7
7 / 2 == 3 (integer math)
3 - 1 + 1 == 3
6 - 3 == 3
num = (1 + 3) / 2 == 2
```

EDIT: Here's code that returns the sequence you want. Can't guarantee I didn't break your +1 sequence, though :)

```
int NextGuess(int  param) {
    int num;
    static int a=0, b=100;
    static int lastGuess = 50;

    //printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, interval, lastGuess);
    if (param==-1) //less
    {
        b = lastGuess;
    }
    else if (param==1) //greater
    {
        a = lastGuess + 1;
    }

    lastGuess = (a+b) / 2;

    return lastGuess;
}
```

Comment: but.. what am I supposed to do to make it a 1? how come it got all the other numbers right, but not this one?

Comment: I suppose it's arguable whether the others are 'correct'. One might say that 13 is a better guess than 12 after 25. Does the assignment specify what values it should return given this particular case?

Comment: it does, there are examples of input and output. i'll edit the question to include them! i got all the others right except the last number (that is 2 instead of 1). the parameter==-1 is supposed to decrease the interval that was (0,100), to make it (0,50), then (0,25) etc; you see it always returns the half of that interval..

Comment: I think one small change will fix it to match your `1,-1,-1,1` output

Comment: Won't matter too much, unless there's a test case of 6 `-1`s in a row. Seems to work fine with the proper interval, though

Answer (score 0):

Rather than criticize, let me show you a couple of counterexamples. Consider the following:

```
struct intrange {
    int   minimum;
    int   maximum;
};
```

These limits are inclusive. You can pass structures by value, and assign them just like any other type. To split such a structure, you could use

```
struct intrange  intrange_split(const struct intrange  range,
                                const int              half)
{
    /* Midpoint of the range, rounding towards zero */
    const int        midpoint = (range.minimum + range.maximum) / 2;
    struct intrange  result;

    if (half > 0) {
        /* Upper half, including midpoint. */
        result.minimum = midpoint;
        result.maximum = range.maximum;
    } else
    if (half < 0) {
        /* Lower half, excluding midpoint. */
        result.minimum = range.minimum;
        result.maximum = midpoint - 1;
    } else {
        /* No change. */
        result = range;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The above `intrange_split()` function takes an intrange structure `range` as a parameter, and an int `half` to indicate how to split it. There are no error checks.

If you wanted to operate on a structure passed by reference, you could use say

```
int intrange_split(struct intrange *range, int half)
{
    int midpoint;

    /* No range? Invalid range? */
    if (!range || range->maximum < range->minimum)
        return -1; /* Invalid range. */

    /* Note: This could overflow. */
    midpoint = (range->minimum + range->maximum) / 2;

    if (half == 1) {
        /* Upper half, including midpoint. */
        range->minimum = midpoint;
    } else
    if (half == -1) {
        /* Lower half, excluding midpoint. */
        range->maximum = midpoint - 1;
    } else {
        /* Invalid operation. */
        return -1;
    }

    /* Verify range is valid (non-empty). */
    if (range->maximum < range->minimum)
        return -1;

    /* Range is valid, and not empty. */
    return 0;
}
```

It is more common to use the return value to represent success/error in C, because unlike C++, there are no exceptions.  (You could also use assertions, or print an error message and [`abort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) or [`exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), depending on whether the error is recoverable or not.)

In all above cases, I used the logic that `midpoint` is halfway between `minimum` and `maximum`, rounded towards zero; and that `midpoint` belongs to the upper range. It is up to you to choose *how* you define it, as long as you make the choice explicitly, and document it.  See how much simpler these approaches are?

It is also common to use preprocessor macros or static inline functions for initializing variables. In this case, for example

```
#define  INTRANGE_INIT(min, max)  { min, max }

static inline struct intrange intrange_define(const int minimum,
                                              const int maximum)
{
    struct intrange  result = { minimum, maximum };
    return result;
}
```

so that in your code, you can declare a range using e.g. `struct intrange  my_range = INTRANGE_INIT(0, 100);`. Sure, you can also initialize it using `struct intrange my_range = { 0, 100 };`, or even `struct intrange my_range; my_range = intrange_define(0, 100);`.

As long as the implementation is readable and easy to understand, it is fine.  I tend to prefer the preprocessor macro style myself, but that is purely a style issue.

Remember to write comments that describe your design and intent, not what the code does. That skill is as important as programming itself. You'll find that in most cases, code that can only be written and not maintained, is not worth the electricity to run it on.

(And never ever get into the habit of thinking you'll add error checking and security stuff later. Because you won't. Nobody ever does. If they try, they invariably fail. This is because robustness and security can only be designed in, not added afterwards.)

Comment: thank you! but that's a bit too complicated for my very limited knowlegde :-( this is actually supposed to be a really simple function. it is supposed to take -1, 1 and 0 as parameters and return a number.